# Assigning images to a picturebox from an imagelist

Tags: arrays, vb.net, imagelist

I have to assign 16 images that are randomized in an array to pictureboxes. I came up with the idea of creating an imagelist and then assign them to the pictureboxes.
Is there a way to shorten this?
This is the code that I came up with:

```
For i = 0 To FotoArray.Length - 1
                ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(FotoArray(i)))
            Next
    
            PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(0)
        PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(1)
        PictureBox3.Image = ImageList1.Images(2)
        PictureBox4.Image = ImageList1.Images(3)
        PictureBox5.Image = ImageList1.Images(4)
        PictureBox6.Image = ImageList1.Images(5)
        PictureBox7.Image = ImageList1.Images(6)
        PictureBox8.Image = ImageList1.Images(7)
        PictureBox9.Image = ImageList1.Images(8)
        PictureBox10.Image = ImageList1.Images(9)
        PictureBox11.Image = ImageList1.Images(10)
        PictureBox12.Image = ImageList1.Images(11)
        PictureBox13.Image = ImageList1.Images(12)
        PictureBox14.Image = ImageList1.Images(13)
        PictureBox15.Image = ImageList1.Images(14)
        PictureBox16.Image = ImageList1.Images(15)
```

and also for this

Is there a way to make the same for this labels?

```
Label1.Tag = FotoArray(0)
Label2.Tag = FotoArray(1)
Label3.Tag = FotoArray(2)
Label4.Tag = FotoArray(3)
Label5.Tag = FotoArray(4)
Label6.Tag = FotoArray(5)
Label7.Tag = FotoArray(6)
Label8.Tag = FotoArray(7)
Label9.Tag = FotoArray(8)
Label10.Tag = FotoArray(9)
Label11.Tag = FotoArray(10)
Label12.Tag = FotoArray(11)
Label16.Tag = FotoArray(12)
Label13.Tag = FotoArray(13)
Label15.Tag = FotoArray(14)
Label14.Tag = FotoArray(15)
```

Comment: Is this for WinForms or another platform?

Comment: It is for Windows Forms App(.NET Framework) - Visual Basic

Comment: You can use the answer I put below, replace `PictureBox` with `Label` and then use `FotoArray` instead of `ImageList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [OfType Linq extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) to help make this code succint such as:

```
    Dim pictureBoxes As List(Of PictureBox) = Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).ToList()

    For counter As Integer = 0 To pictureBoxes.Count - 1
        Dim pb As PictureBox = pictureBoxes(counter)
        pb.Image = ImageList1.Images(counter)
    Next
```

From MSDN:

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Comment: I thank you so much. It solved my problem. That's an interesting method that I had no idea that it existed.

Comment: @Zarb Glad to be of assistance. There is a load of functionality in Linq that can be used in a variety of imaginative ways to make your coding tasks much easier